# Step down 100 V to 26 V with some specific requirements

Tags: circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, step-down

I'm trying to repair an [HP 8555A](https://www.hpmemoryproject.org/timeline/bob_devries/hp8555a_01.htm) spectrum analyzer module which shows problems in the step-down power module.

I'd like to replace the module which steps down the 100 VDC coming from the mainframe unit to 26.5 VDC used to power some other linear power supply which steps that further down to 20 V and 10 V. The requirements for this power module as far as I can tell from the service manuals are:

- Input voltage 100 VDC +/- 10%
- Output voltage under load 26 VDC +/- 1V
- Continuous output power ~8.1 W
- This gives an output current of ~313 mA
- Overload protection
- Switching frequency of ~ 100 kHz (should not be too high to creep into spectrum measurement)
- Efficiency doesn't really matter but should not be under 70%
- Size of the enclosure (metal can referenced to ground) is ca. 7x7x2 cm

What are my options considering that:

- I am on a budget in that I'd like to avoid boutique ICs which are hard to find or cost a lot. Say 5 to 10€ per IC max.
- I don't know how to or have the equipment to wind transformers.
- Possibly a one-chip solution with a few passives instead of a discrete components approach should be preferred (because harder to design and debug, hard to get right, hard to protect).

Comment: Are these voltages all DC? 100VDC to 26VDC 10W converter ICs aren't too hard to find, Texas instruments for example have 12 different options, all of which are less than $5.

Comment: You mention transformers; does that mean it requires an isolation transformer?

Comment: Wiring transformers isn't any different than wiring any other component. If you mean winding them, that's also not difficult, just tedious, but you can generally get suitable transformers already assembled for flyback or forward converters from companies like Coilcraft for not very much money.

Comment: if, in the other hand, the 100V is AC then a single chip solution doesn't exist (you can find a DIN rail module that can do it, but it's wont fit inside the instrument). In this case you're going to need a transformer, a rectifier, a smoother and a buck converter to step down to 26V DC.

Comment: How much space do you have to fit the converter?

Comment: I updated the question with responses to comments. It doesn't require isolation, no. Yes I'm thinking about a switching regulator of some kind. Space can be a bit of a problem.

Comment: Cut the old one open. You might find something useful, like the transformer you need. Or you might just spot the problem.

Comment: The old one is repaired and kinda works except it has some weird problems I can't figure out how to fix: after ca. 20 seconds of normal operation it starts producing some erratic noise (electrical and audible) and I don't want to rely on that design any longer. I don't either want to pull the transformer out and re-use it since I want to keep the old circuit intact (as much as possible)

Answer (score 1):

UC3843 is fine for something like that, or maybe even LNK626 or friends. Note that it must be powered either from an independent low-voltage supply already present (auxiliary supply), or using a startup circuit (usually a pullup resistor, then say the 10 or 20V final outputs, or the 26V intermediate output, can power it once operating.

This will require a transformer, for which any standard 85-265V to 24V inverter transformer will suffice.  These are regularly stocked and made by Wurth, Coilcraft, etc.

I'm not aware of any direct-input buck regulator ICs, at least that are readily available, or cheap.  Offhand, I see LTC3638 available at Digi-Key -- for $26 in singles.  There are few high voltage buck controllers (external switch) as well.